# disable / remove jquery chosen features

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I am little stuck at this, 
How do i disable all chosen features,

In simple words, i don't need that every time i write,

```
<select>
  <option value="">select value</option>
  <option value="key">value</option>
</select>
```

and chosen plugin automatically convert it into chosen features.

I am not using below code in document ready handler,

```
$('#my_select').chosen();
```

i need to show a simple select.

Comment: The plugin will only affect the elements that you target. If you only want it to be applied to certain elements, then give those elements a class, and target that, eg. `$('select.addChosen').chosen();` - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/3JqXs/1/)

Comment: but if my select element throughout the site is embedded with this plugin, then how do i disable one, in simple words vice versa of your answer.

Comment: Well you'd have to give the element an identifier, and exclude it in the selector `$('select:not(".noChosen")').chosen()` (although, doing it this way seems counterintuitive to me)

Comment: many thanks, that's what i mean..